# How to solve "org.json and document cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-data-api

I want to try some similar to this : https://www.joe0.com/2016/03/05/youtube-data-api-v3-how-to-search-youtube-using-java-and-extract-video-id-of-the-most-relevant-result/, but i have understood this libraries don't work with the new youtube settings, and when i import the JSOUP libary java says can't  import the first line. How can i do the same algorithm?

edit 1: my problems are:
[in the line 4,  org,json cannot be resolved
lines 12 and 14 document cannot be resolved to a type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUh8O.png)

and [in the line 17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VX8Q.png)

my code:

```
package buscador;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

public class Search_YT {
    String keyword = "how to make apple pie filling" 
    keyword = keyword.replace(" ", "+");

    String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&order=rating&q=" + keyword + "&key=\r\n" + "AIzaSyAHcCYRDLHQH1SBAoydbZqcfb4iVEn11tI";

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10 * 1000).get();

    String getJson = doc.text();
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(getJson ).nextValue();

    System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("videoId"));

}
```

Comment: Hello Allan! Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Can you share your code and the error that you are getting?

Comment: Hello Allan! did my Answer help you? If yes, please mark it as correct!

Answer (score 0):

For your initial question:

> "How can i search in youtube using java and get the most relevant video
>   id"

you really have to develop your own search algoritm for it, I don't think someone here will write you such. I can give you tips if you want:
- You may want to search for a certain term, get the video list and then go for the title of each video and see if it contains your keyword. Not really complex, but just for you to start your journey :D

Next:

I think the Document is a Jsoup class. Just import it. Click on that Lamp to the left of it and hit 'import', as you have already successfully added Jsoup to your project.

Moving on:
For the JSONObject class you need the gson library. If you use gradle, you can just add it like that:

```
dependencies {

//other implementations
//...

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
  //^^^^this line adds gson to your project
}
```

Or here's the link to the gson jar libraries downloads:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.2/
(pretty sure you need the "gson-2.8.2.jar", not the javadoc)
Whatever serves you more

Furthermore you are missing a semicolon in line 7:

```
String keyword = "how to make apple pie filling";
                                            //  ^ see that?
```

next I'm pretty sure you can't reassign valuables in the class level, you would need to do that in a method: `keyword = keyword.replace...blabla`

create a method for example like that inside of your class:

```
public void hello() {

keyword =keyword.replace(" ","+");

String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&order=rating&q=" + keyword + "&key=\r\n" + "AIzaSyAHcCYRDLHQH1SBAoydbZqcfb4iVEn11tI";

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10 * 1000).get();

String getJson = doc.text();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(getJson).nextValue();

System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("videoId"));

}
```

Comment: i'm having problems wiht the library, it was supossed the library i already imported have this. Whatever, thank you so much with the help :), i'm very new in java

Comment: You have the`Gson` library in your project? I did not see it in the picture ( not `Jsoup`)
You're free to upvote my answer if I helped you ;) I will update my answer if you give me more information